# How to generate sequence diagram from cpp code in windows?

Tags: clang, clang++, clang-format, clang-static-analyzer

I know that clang-uml can generate cpp code to sequence diagram. But I am unable to use it. I have installed it but some configuration issue occurred.

I want to generate sequence code from cpp code.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please give an example of some input and the corresponding output you want.